# How use %like% in sql statement wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, wp-query, menus

i use a **like** %text% statement in wordpress:

```
SELECT *  FROM location  WHERE name LIKE "%on" OR name LIKE "%on%"
```

i tried anything but it's not run:

```
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb -> prepare("SELECT *  FROM location  WHERE name LIKE %1s OR name LIKE %2s", '%'.like_escape('on'), '%'.like_escape('on').'%'), ARRAY_A);
```

please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$wpdb->prepare()` doesn't actually fully support `sprintf()` placeholders.

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders):

> The query parameter for prepare accepts sprintf()-like placeholders. The %s (string), %d (integer) and %f (float) formats are supported.

It's not entirely obvious from that but the argument swapping formats (e.g. `%1$d`) are not supported *(in any case you have the incorrect syntax: it should be `%2$s` instead of `%2s`)*

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT *  FROM location  
         WHERE name LIKE %s OR name LIKE %s", 
         '%'.$wpdb->esc_like('on'), 
         '%'.$wpdb->esc_like('on').'%'
), ARRAY_A);
```

I'm assuming 'on' might be replaced by a unknown value - otherwise `$wpdb->prepare()` isn't necessary. On an unrelated note, the second condition in your SQL makes the first obsolete.